# What is the difference Between Extends and Instantiation?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop

What is the difference Between Extends and Instantiation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you instantiate a class you are making an instance of that class. In other words you are making a copy of that class. [Read more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_%28computer_science%29)

When you extend a class you inherit that class' attributes and methods. This way you can reuse that code in your own class without having to rewrite that functionality. [Read more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Comment: Instantiation will do copy the entire class, but extends not, its just reuse the existing code. Got it now.

Thanks.